# How can I mark a podcast as "Listened to" on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, podcasts

Is there a way to mark a podcast as "Listened to" on my iPhone/iPod? Occasionally I get podcasts that I've already heard, and I was hoping there was a quick way to mark them as played.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could start playing it and quickly fast-forward to the end.  Or, you could use a different app for podcasts, such as [Instacast](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instacast/id420368235?mt=8) or [Pocket Casts](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pocket-casts/id414834813?mt=8).

Comment: I currently scrub to the end and hit play, but I was hoping there was a more elegant solution. I think in one of the early iOS releases you could side swipe to do it, but now that just deletes, and it will just show up again next time I sync. Thanks for the app suggestions though.